# Join two pandas dataframes based on line order

Tags: join, pandas, concatenation

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 I want to join. Their indexes are not the same and they don't have any common columns. What I want is to join them based on the order of the rows, i.e. join the first row of df1 with the first row of df2, the second row of df1 with the second row of df2, etc.

Example:

```
df1:
     'A'   'B'
  0   1     2
  1   3     4
  2   5     6 

df2:
     'C'   'D'
  0   7     8
  3   9     10
  5   11    12
```

Should give

```
     'A'    'B'   'C'   'D'
  0   1      2     7     8
  3   3      4     9     10
  5   5      6     11    12
```

I don't care about the indexes in the final dataframe. I tried reindexing df1 with the indexes of df2 but could not make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign to `df1` index of `df2` and then use `join`:

```
df1.index = df2.index
res = df1.join(df2)

In [86]: res
Out[86]: 
   'A'  'B'  'C'  'D'
0    1    2    7    8
3    3    4    9   10
5    5    6   11   12
```

Or you could do it in one line with `set_index`:

```
In [91]: df1.set_index(df2.index).join(df2)
Out[91]: 
   'A'  'B'  'C'  'D'
0    1    2    7    8
3    3    4    9   10
5    5    6   11   12
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index()], axis=1)
```

The `reset_index`() calls make the indices the same, then, `concat` with `axis=1` simply joins horizontally.

Comment: As I understand OP expected to get indices with `0 3 5` like in `df2` but not the `0 1 2` which you'll get after `reset_index`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's true: "I don't care about the indexes in the final dataframe."

Comment: Nonetheless, have an upvote in appreciation of the comment :-)

Comment: yes, the final indexes don't matter. All of the solutions work, thank you all!

Comment: @AmiTavory yes, missed that part of the text (or may be that was one of the multiple edits). Upvoted as well

Comment: @AntonProtopopov That's fine. I appreciate the comment in any case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try to join them (doing this it performs the join on the index, which is the same for the two DataFrame due to `reset_index`):

```
In [18]: df1.join(df2.reset_index(drop=True))
Out[18]: 
   'A'  'B'  'C'  'D'
0    1    2    7    8
1    3    4    9   10
2    5    6   11   12
```